# String concatenation OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am fiddling around with Java.lang.String and using '+' operator on them. I am curious to find out why the below output is obtained:

With the below code, I can get Thousands's of iteration and no memory exception is thrown:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "hello";
        int count = 1;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(count++);
            str = str + "newString";
        }
    }
```

But, When I add the 'str' to itself, I get OutOfMemoryError exception just after 20-30 iterations:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "hello";
        int count = 1;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(count++);
            str = str + "newString" +str;
        }
    }
```

I am using eclipse on 32 bit OS and no additional args such as Xms or Xmx

Comment: how many iterations correctly??

Comment: sysout string you will understood

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do

```
str = str + "newString";
```

your string grows linearly by 9 characters on every iteration.

```
Iteration    String length
1            5
2            14
3            23
4            32
5            41
6            50
...
30           266
```

On the other hand, if you do

```
str = str + "newString" + str;
```

your string grows exponentially. It becomes twice as long + 9 characters on every iteration.

```
Iteration    String length
1            5
2            19
3            47
4            103
5            215
6            439
...
30           7516192759
```

Answer (score 0):

just a piece of math:

pow(2, 20) is much greater than a few thousands. 
The string is 5 characters long and you double it in every loop step. After 20 steps your string is (without appending the "newString" string) 5*pow(2,20) long. This is a length of 5 242 880 Characters and is much more then 5+9*1000 = 45000 characters in the first loop.

**EDIT** to by correct: in the second loop you have 5*pow(2,20) + 9*sum(pow(2,i),i,0,19).